# Getting Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F0D when posting to a service in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, httpclient

When I am trying to post a data to an API using HttpClient in Windows Phone 8.1, I am always getting `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F0D` exception. In fiddler, it works fine.

```
try
{  
    var requestbody="json data"
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), new Uri(addressUri));
    msg.Content = new HttpStringContent(requestbody);
    msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(msg).AsTask();
}           
catch (Exception ex)
{
    getting **Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F0D**
}
```

Please tell me what went wrong?

---FYI----

For getting additional information about the HRESULT code : Follow this [WebErrorStatus enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.web.weberrorstatus)

```
  var exceptionDetail = WebError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);

  if (exceptionDetail == WebErrorStatus.HostNameNotResolved)
  {
    //
  }
```

Comment: Which `HttpClient` are you using. And what is the exception message?

Comment: FYI That HRESULT is WININET_E_INVALID_CA "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect".

Comment: @Fred Am using Windows.Web HttpClient in Windows Phone 8.1 xaml project

Comment: @DecadeMoon so decade, what i need to clarify ? or What i need to do with this? In fiddler it is working properly. Am  using same url with same post data.

Comment: https? Maybe an ssl certificate issue?

Comment: @Oliver yes it is https . What i need to do it working ?any suggestion

Comment: Sounds like the certificate needs to be installed on the phone in order for you to make the https call. 
I've not done any  windows phone 8.1 development but hopefully this gives you a direction

Comment: What's the endpoint url? It's probably an issue with the server you're connecting to. (This kind of error would normally be shown as a red "danger" page in Internet Explorer signifying some kind of SSL certificate error.)

Comment: @Decade But why it is working fine with fiddler ? Don't it need certificate ?

Comment: @Oliver But why it is working fine with fiddler ? Don't it need certificate ?

Comment: Fiddler makes it's own certificate. Does Fiddler show any SSL errors that it may have ignored for that request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a certificate related problem. Maybe you are using SSL. While lots of programs gracefully override missing certificates if not explicitly necessary (e.g.: browsers) the `HttpClient` is pretty sensitive against that.

You should try to download the certificate for the connection you're using and store the cert file in your assets folder. When your app starts, push it into the certificate store. This is a snippet I am using in one of my apps. Maybe this makes your exception go away.

Read more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx

```
// Add our custom certificate
try
{
    // Read the contents of the Certificate file
    System.Uri certificateFile = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/ca.cer");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(certificateFile);
    Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer certBlob = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

    // Create an instance of the Certificate class using the retrieved certificate blob contents
    Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate rootCert = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate(certBlob);

    // Get access to the TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities for your own app (not the system one)
    Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStore trustedStore = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities;

    // Add the certificate to the TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities store for your app
    trustedStore.Add(rootCert);
}
catch (Exception oEx)
{
   // Catch that exception. We don't really have a choice here..
   var msg = oEx.Message;
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. I will check with our server team for providing the certificate if needed. And will update you the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to bypass the error with this code:

```
var baseFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
baseFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.InvalidCertificateAuthorityPolicy);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(baseFilter);
```

**This merely silences the error** rather than solving the problem, though. I'm not too knowledgeable with SSL errors, and this may not be a safe option, and may not pass app certification. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.ignorableservercertificateerrors.aspx):

> SSL server certificate errors should only be ignored in advanced scenarios. Disregarding server certificate errors classified as either Ignorable or Fatal may result in the loss of privacy or integrity of the content passed over the SSL session.

Comment: Besides, on Windows Phone project I had to put "Untrusted" instead of "InvalidCertificateAuthorityPolicy", otherwise the exception is raised about unknown option value.

Answer (score 0):

Received the same Error as originator.  I do not use a proxy.

This worked for me. netsh winhttp reset proxy
Next Fax transmitted without error.

Answer (score -1):

Experienced the 0x80072efd problem. Has cost me hours if not days to solve. The solution that gave instant resolution is the following command from a admin command prompt:

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`