# HttpClient.SendRequestAsync throws System.Exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a generic method to sending HTTP operations using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`.
The method contains the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, new Uri(URL));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
   request.Content = new HttpStringContent(param, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
```

where `param` is a json string with parameters, can be empty.

Right after sending the request the program throws an exception with `HRESULT: 0x80072EE7`, but I haven't found a way for resolving the issue.

Any idea of what could be making this crash?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972887/getting-exception-from-hresult-0x80072f0d-when-posting-to-a-service-in-windows

Comment: Yes! I've taken a look at this post, but the HRESULT code is different, I don't know how the HRESULT has to do with the actual reason of the crash but anyway I was already trying to solve this all following the answer of the post you mention.